# top/ps/mpstat showing different output

Tags: debian, ps, top, load

When my `top` shows a load of 19/20 and my `ps` shows

```
root@server:/home/nohup# ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -5
%CPU   PID USER     COMMAND
122131 18695 mysql  /usr/sbin/mysqld  xxxxx
0.1   961 root     [kdmflush]
0.1   937 root     [kdmflush]
0.1  1025 root     [jbd2/dm-2-8]
```

But `mpstat` shows

```
root@server:/home/nohup# mpstat
Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 (sms-db3)  06/13/2014  _x86_64_    (16 CPU)

09:35:42 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
09:35:42 PM  all    2.38    0.00    0.15    0.15    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00   97.29
```

`strace` shows that `mpstat` is reading from `/proc/stat` to fetch the processor load.

Which one should I believe? What is causing this difference, or am I using it wrong? I am using Debian Squeeze 2.6.32-5-amd64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian Squeeze is running `procps 3.2.8` which was a very old version of the library. `mpstat` shows numbers similar to `top`, so it is basically the numbers of the last few seconds. `ps` shows the stats from when the process started.

The numbers are unusual though which points to something overflowing or wrapping. If you want to work out what was happening right at this second, then `mpstat` seems more accurate. `top` should be close to those numbers too and if it isn't, I'd be curious to see what its summary area was showing.

PS. It is better to see how "busy" the process was across its lifetime.